# C# Singleton Pattern with new Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, msmq

I have a `listenerclass` which has methods listening msmque, and receive prices, and distribute depending on some conditions. Getting prices so fast, and performace is very important that point. When I reading code I realized that each received item from msmque creates new Task to make some process and distribute price.

Here is the thing when a price received, the new price comes before first price distribute. To solve that problem each price use another task, but `orderService.DistributePrice` coded as a singleton pattern, I can not be sure that, when I create new task, each task create their own singleton, or each new task uses the same singelton instance.

If yes, code is completely fail. Please let me now. Thank you

My msmque listener below,

```
   private static void PriceQueuePeekCompleted(Object source, PeekCompletedEventArgs asyncResult)
    {
        var mq = (MessageQueue)source;
        var recvMessage = mq.Receive();

        if (recvMessage != null)
        {
            var price = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FinancialInstrumentPrice>((string)recvMessage.Body);
         Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>Distributer.Instance.DistributePrice(price) );   
        }
        mq.BeginPeek();}
```

And DistributerInstance distribute the prices,

```
 internal class Distributer
{
    private static Distributer _instance;
    public List<IOrderService> _PriceListeners { get; set; }

    private  Distributer()
    {
    }

    public static Distributer Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new Distributer();

            }
            return _instance;               
        }
    }

    private void DistributePrice(FinancialInstrumentPrice _priceToDistribute)
    {
        foreach (IOrderService orderService in _PriceListeners)
        {
            orderService.GetPrice(_priceToDistribute);
        }
    }
}


public class FinancialInstrumentPrice {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}


public interface IOrderService
{
    void GetPrice(FinancialInstrumentPrice _priceToDistribute);
}
```

At that point prices comes so fast from msmque, so before first price is distributed, second price is came, to solve that problem I am using Task.Factory to create new tasks for each received price, however as you can see above, Singelton pattern implemented to Distributer class. As far as I know there is only one instance in memory if singelton used. In this situation, what will happend. I am creating new tasks for each price, on the other hand different tasks try to use singelton object. Each new tasks can create their own Distributer class in memory or each task try to use same Distributer class instance ?
if they try to use same Distributer class instance, it is fail.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not very clear from your question what is failing in your code, or if it is actually failing. Unless there is a bug in your orderservice code, a "task(that) create their own singleton" should never happen. I think you should include the code of orderservice, and/or it's instanciation/singleton implementation in your question, it *might* clear things up.

Comment: I tried to make my question more clear

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's making less sense. You say that your "code is fail", but you don't say why. Is there an exception? Or an functional problem? what exactly is failing? "if they try to use same Distributer class instance, it is fail" - well the idea of singleton is just that - that the application only uses one instance. So If you don't want that for some reason, do not use the singleton pattern.

Comment: I am in fail not make sense. let me explain. As you can see I get price from msmque, for each recieved price create new task. 


Distributer.Instance is singelton. I am curious about it. when project started and received prices from msmque, what will happen Distributer.Instance part? each new task will use same distributer.instance ? because it should has only one instance or each task can create their own Distributer.Instance ? 

thank you

Comment: Well, first of all, the Singleton implementation you are using is not thread-safe. Google c# thread-safe singleton. 

Once the singleton is instantiated correctly, all tasks will use only one instance. Tasks will *not* create their own instances.

Your question is overly complicated, I think what you are actually wondering is: How does static variables work. What are their purpose in a multithreaded context. What is the singleton pattern and what is its purpose.

Comment: Or actually maybe you could just be asking me how to make your singleton thread-safe... I'm not sure we'll figure this out :P

Comment: Actually I am going to be glad if you explain how to make my singelton thread-safe, also want to ask, if multiple tasks try to use thread-safe singelton object. what will happen ?

Comment: We are running in circles here... One last try, Ill try to be short. as I said before: with a correctly instantiated singleton, all tasks will use only one instance. Tasks will not create their own instances.

Comment: I'm guessing the singleton of is set up somewhere earlier, in a single-threaded context, when _PriceListeners is populated (or it wouldnt do anything). If this is the case, no need to make instanciation thread-safe.

Comment: Ok. I got the idea at the end. many thanks..